# Why does it only display one line? ie Why is it only reading the first line of the textfile?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to read from a textfile where the data is comma delimited per line(textfile provided).
After the line is read, I separate the data and finally send it to my view as a list.

Problem is that it only reads/displays the first line.

Text File:

```
John,Smith,02-05-1969,0001,700000,Manager,None  
Jane,Doe,04-01-1977,0002,600000,Employee,John  
Jim,Bean,11-09-1985,0003,650000,Employee,Jane  
Roger,Wilco,19-12-1990,0004,200000,Trainee,Jane  
Susan,Roe,22-06-1995,0005,180000,Trainee,Jane
```

Controller:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using EpiUseTechAssessment.ViewModels;
    using System.IO;

    namespace EpiUseTechAssessment.Controllers
    {
        public class HRManagerController : Controller
        {
    // GET: HRManager
            public ActionResult HRManager()
            {
                List<EmployeeViewModel> employees= GetTestData();
                return View(employees);
            }

                private List<EmployeeViewModel> GetTestData()
            {

                string[] Lines;
                string filepath = @"D:Employees.txt";
                StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filepath);
                string Name;
                string Surname;
                string Birthdate;
                int EmpNum;
                int Salary;
                string Role;
                string Reports;
                List<EmployeeViewModel> employees = new      List<EmployeeViewModel>();

                while (file.EndOfStream == false)
                {
                    //Read textfile
                    Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

                    //Seperate data and assign
                    foreach (string line in Lines)
                    {
                        string[] L = line.Split(',');
                        Name = L[0];
                        Surname = L[1];
                        Birthdate = L[2];
                        EmpNum = Convert.ToInt32(L[3]);
                        Salary = Convert.ToInt32(L[4]);
                        Role = L[5];
                        Reports = L[6];

                    //Send to ViewModel
                    EmployeeViewModel emp = new EmployeeViewModel(Name,         Surname, Birthdate, EmpNum, Salary, Role, Reports);
                    employees.Add(emp);
                    return employees;
                    }

                }
                file.Close();
                return (employees);

            }
```

View:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace EpiUseTechAssessment.ViewModels
    {
        public class EmployeeViewModel
        {
            public string _Name { get; set; }
            public string _Surname { get; set; }
            public string _Birthdate { get; set; }
            public int _EmpNum { get; set; }
            public int _Salary { get; set; }
            public string _Role { get; set; }
            public string _Reports { get; set; }

            public EmployeeViewModel(string name, string surname, string         birthdate, int empnum, int salary, string role, string reports)
            {
                _Name = name;
                _Surname = surname;
                _Birthdate = birthdate;
                _EmpNum = empnum;
                _Salary = salary;
                _Role = role;
                _Reports = reports;
            }
        }
    }
```

Class:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace EpiUseTechAssessment.ViewModels
    {
        public class EmployeeViewModel
        {
            public string _Name { get; set; }
            public string _Surname { get; set; }
            public string _Birthdate { get; set; }
            public int _EmpNum { get; set; }
            public int _Salary { get; set; }
            public string _Role { get; set; }
            public string _Reports { get; set; }

            public EmployeeViewModel(string name, string surname, string birthdate, int empnum, int salary, string role, string reports)
            {
                _Name = name;
                _Surname = surname;
                _Birthdate = birthdate;
                _EmpNum = empnum;
                _Salary = salary;
                _Role = role;
                _Reports = reports;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you are calling `return employees;` from within While loop?

Comment: There are libraries to read, parse and type CSV files for you that will work better and faster.  Otherwise, this doesnt seem very [mcve]

Comment: What @RahulSingh said -- you are returning your result both within your `for...each` and within your `while`. You want to return it *after* you have finished building it up completely (ie outside of both of those loops)

Comment: Thanks, I have removed `Return employees` and only have it outside the loops. Now my view won't load at all? @RahulSingh and @Jonathan

Comment: You open a StreamReader (named file) and then read directly from the file by path (ignoring that reader). So remove the StreamReader and the "while"

Comment: The while loop is infinite, because you never read from `file`, so your `file.EndOfStream` will never become `true`. Remove the `while` (and the StreamReader)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Thanks you are right! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You are currently returning a result from within the loop.  This will terminate the loop after the first iteration.

Try the following, I have separated out the parsing of the csv record as a function.  The key points are to use the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) for the StreamReader and to return the result outside the loop.  The `using` statement will ensure the stream is disposed of correctly once it is no longer required.  You should add additional error handling for instances where the file does not exist, or cannot be read etc.

```
private List<EmployeeViewModel> GetTestData(string filePath)
{
    List<EmployeeViewModel> employees = new List<EmployeeViewModel>();

    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filepath))
    {
        // Read all records from the textfile
        string[] Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

        //Separate data and assign
        foreach (string line in Lines)
        {
            employees.Add(ParseAsEmployeeModel(line));
        }
    }

    // Will return an empty array when no records are available
    // Depending on use case a null may be preferable
    return employees;
}

private EmployeeViewModel ParseAsEmployeeModel(string csvRecord)
{
    string[] L = line.Split(',');
    string Name = L[0];
    string Surname = L[1];
    DateTime Birthdate = DateTime.Parse(L[2]); // TODO : error checking to ensure date is valid
    int EmpNum = Convert.ToInt32(L[3]); // TODO: You are losing leading zeros - is this correct?
    int Salary = Convert.ToInt32(L[4]);
    string Role = L[5];
    string Reports = L[6];

    return new EmployeeViewModel(Name, Surname, Birthdate, EmpNum, Salary, Role, Reports);
}
```

In addition to the above, I would recommend storing the birthdate as a DateTime rather than string as below.

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string _Name { get; set; }
    public string _Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime _Birthdate { get; set; }
    public int _EmpNum { get; set; }
    public int _Salary { get; set; }
    public string _Role { get; set; }
    public string _Reports { get; set; }

    public EmployeeViewModel(string name, string surname, DateTime birthdate, int empnum, int salary, string role, string reports)
    {
        _Name = name;
        _Surname = surname;
        _Birthdate = birthdate;
        _EmpNum = empnum;
        _Salary = salary;
        _Role = role;
        _Reports = reports;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, i have changed the birthdate to datetime but now its displaying the date in the incorrect format and the addition of time, how can I get the correct format and not display the time?

Comment: @MarkoOreb Try the standard format string  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings or if they do not suit your need the custom - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings